# why dropdownlist adds the items again on reload ?(asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

hello and i'm sorry if this has been covered before.

there is an error that is annoying me for 2 days now .

i have a page which will load when the user click on a "BMW" logo
when the page loads the dropdownlist (called "model") will get values from a certain list .

the problem here that whenever i refresh the page (F5) it adds the items multiple times even if i added "model.item.clear();" method.

**so the bottom line is that i want to add the items only once , even if i reloaded the page (F5)**.

the NewTransaction.aspx is the page which have the dropdownlist ("model"),
this is the code from another page which has the "BMW logo"

```
<a href="NewTransaction.aspx?type=Car&company=BMW"><img class="logo" style="width:200px" src="images/BMW.png" /></a>
```

this is the code of the dropdownlist the NewTransaction.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="model" runat="server" CssClass="inputs" OnSelectedIndexChanged="model_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

here the part where i enter the data from the list that has objects of "Car".
note that this code is in the **"Page_load" method**

```
switch (Server.UrlDecode(Request["company"]).ToString())
        {

            case "BMW":
                model.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (Car n in OverLand.car)
                    {
                        if (n.made == "BMW")
                        {
                            model.Items.Add(n.model);
                        }
                    }


                break;
```

[picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxRa.png) .

note that it has many other "cases" for other companies.

thank you.

EDIT : i tried the following

```
switch (Server.UrlDecode(Request["company"]).ToString())
        {
            case "BMW":

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    foreach (Car n in OverLand.car)
                    {
                        if (n.made == "BMW")
                        {
                            model.Items.Add(n.model);
                        }
                    }
                }        

                break;
```

and then i ran the website in google chrome and it worked BUT then i stopped the it and re-run it again and the dropdownlist added the items like 5 times.
i have no idea what's going on here .-.

**EDIT 2** :so what i noticed that the first time ever everything works fine and when i try to reload the page google chrome puts this message to me : i.imgur.com/EVjLxGD.png .

however if i closed the project and re-open it again , it adds the data multiple time ( i think it's equal to how many times the page refreshed + how many times i choose a model from the model list ) and to prevent that i have to stop the site from the IIS , but of course that's just a way to see if everything else is working fine or not , i can't think of an idea to stop it except making a method which will check how many models i got in my database for BMW and put that counter in a variable and put another condition in the "if" condition i already use to add the models to the list to stop adding after when dropdownlist.Items.Count >Counter , but i'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: is it a typo or You have to use `model.Items.Clear();`?

Comment: Put the population of dropdownlist inside :  if (!IsPostBack) { }

Comment: it was just a typo yeah , i edited it now .

Comment: i did try to add the "isPostBack" but nothing happens

Comment: Why did you put the postback check in the switch case? Put the entire switch statement in the postback check.

Comment: @Crowcoder it doesn't matter here , i'm just testing it out with only BMW , because if it is postback it's gonna break the switch anyway.

Comment: @OmarElrayes, ViewState is holding onto the items in the combobox. I suggest you databind it instead of add items manually.

Comment: If the items are added multiple times even after calling `model.Items.Clear()`, that would tell me that the source (`Overland.car`) contains the items multiple times. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

well i can't believe i spent 3 days trying to figure it out and the problem is actually from the "IIS Express" ( local host thingy related to visual studio ).
as i mentioned in the second edit that the first time you run the website everything works fine .

However , if you stop debugging and re-run it , it will add items multiple times.

I tried the same code on one of my friends' laptop and it did work perfectly !
.

what i noticed is that his "IIS" closes automatically(its icon disappear in the task bar when you stop debugging )  when he stops debugging , but for me i have to stop the website manually from the "IIS" icon in the task bar.

I still need an explanation for the duplicate data ( note that the IIS doesn't stop hosting the site when this happens ) and i need a way to stop the IIS when I stop debugging ( note that i'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition ).

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing F5 or refreshing the browser causes it to repeat the last request that it made.  So if you visit a page for the first time (not a postback) and then press F5 - that F5 generated request will also not be a PostBack.  But, if you visit a page (not a postback) and then click a button (causing a postback and raising a click event), pressing F5 will also be a PostBack and will also raise that same click event.

You cant alter whether IsPostBack is true or not.  You will have to devise some other way to know if the list needs to be reloaded - or simply .Clear() it and reload it.

Comment: thank you for explaining how the "postback" works , so what i noticed that the first time ever everything works fine and when i try to reload the page google chrome puts this message to me : http://i.imgur.com/EVjLxGD.png .

Comment: however if i closed the project and re-open it again , it adds the data multiple time ( i think it's equal to how many times the page refreshed + how many times i choose a model from the model list )

Comment: and to prevent that i have to stop the site from the IIS , but of course that's just a way to see if everything else is working fine or not , i can't think of an idea to stop it except making a method which will check how many models i got in my database for BMW and put that counter in a variable and put another condition in the "if" condition i already use to add the models to the list to stop adding after when  dropdownlist.Items.Count >Counter , but i'm still looking for a better solution